# What means my car's displayed diagnosis "GETRIEBEÖL WECHS NÄCHSTE WART."?

Tags: german-to-english, technical-terminology, swiss-standard-german

This looks like a TV series, and here is the 2nd season :).
You may look at the [previous one](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/what-means-my-cars-displayed-diagnosis-k%C3%9Chlmittle-niedr-motor-abstellen) to read detailed information about my car and the 1st occasion where I looked for the sense of its diagnosis.
(micro summary: I'm French and my car's computer speaks German!)

Today again I get a message which lets me quite uncertain:

> GETRIEBEÖL WECHS
>   NÄCHSTE WART.

(please note the final dot, which make me think it might be an abbreviation, since the above two lines exactly reflect the message, restricted to a little display)

Using Google translator I get this tranlation: "transmission oil change next waiting".
From that I guess it might mean that I should operate the oil change of my (automatic) gearbox.

But it happens just one month after my mechanic entirely reconditioned the gearbox!
Of course I will ask him for his advice, but he's French too, so I'd be happy to also get a confirmation from a German speaker...

Comment: Thanks! Using Google translator with this new version I now get "Change gear oil next maintenance", which is much more precise. So it seems that it really regards the gearbox, but doesn't really urge? What do you think? BTW you should post an answer, so I'll accept it.

Comment: are you sure about the spelling of "NÄSTSCHE" (i.e. is this exactly what your car displays?)

Comment: Oops, you're right: I reported it badly in my question, though I'd written it right on my first paper note! And I didn't even noticed that @Iris had corrected it in his answer...

Comment: I did not wonder about the spelling mistakes, because in cFreed's first question were also spelling mistakes in the display of the car.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a contracted or brand service center can change the language of your car's computer fairly easily.

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach You're right, the brand service can change the language easily... but as I reported in my previous question it costs 300 € just for that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"GETRIEBEÖL WECHS" is probably "Getriebeöl wechseln" (Change the gearbox oil) and "NÄCHSTE WART." is probably "Nächste Wartung" (next maintenance).

For me it sounds like it it not urgent, but that you should change the gearbox oil when you have the next maintenance. (Warnung: I have no idea about car mechanics, I just translated and interpreted the German)